# Dynamic and Nested Form Container

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am quite new to front-end programming so I am probably lacking the correct terminology but I am simply looking to create a dynamic/nested form. As shown in the image, I am trying to find a way to contain my form in groups of panels one can say. In the image it will show my current web-page along with sketched out boarder of what I am trying to implement. I using Razor Pages from ASP.NET Core.

https://gyazo.com/c24e74fa2cdd55e4771b2d2715ec8085

I am trying to figure out the correct container object for my form for which I can reproduce everything inside upon the first Add button click. Upon the second Add button click I want to do the same thing but only for the nested container. I want to know if something like this is even possible and if so what should I use to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using razor, when you click the add button what you want to do is render a partial view. Razor syntax: @{Html.RenderPartial("_yourpartialview");}

_yourpartialview is essentially a cshtml file that will not inherit from layout.